# Is there a C# equivalent for findWithinHorizon method

Tags: c#

I need to translate this java code `in.findWithinHorizon("\\[.*?\\]", 4096));`to the right code for C#.

'in' is a variable from getInputStream() used previously in my code.

Comment: maybe you would get a better response if you defined what you need to do. I have no idea what `findWithinHorizon` does. Searches for a far away boat maybe?

Comment: No but it would be fairly easy to write by extracting a substring the size of your desired horizon and then performing a RegEx match on that substring.

Comment: What is the type of `in`?? At least give us sufficient info to *try* and help you

Comment: @sab669 `InputStream`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html. OP left it as a homework for us (sarcastic).

Comment: I am sending a command through a TCP socket connection and the findWithinHorizon() is what is used in Java to send the response back to me, using two arguments: string pattern and an integer. I need to translate in C# and all I have found was the Regex method, but doesn't use an integer as an argument.

Comment: You could look up the implementation at http://grepcode.com/ and rewrite the code in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eric mentioned in the comments, you can do this easily using Regex and a substring:

```
Regex.Match(in.Substring(0, 4095), "\\[.*?\\]");
```

You would benefit from reading [Help With Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We generally expect questions here which are specific, reproducible, and researched. You could likely have found your answer with a bit of googling: as you said, you found the Regex library, and all you needed was a way to limit the search space in the stream. The C# `Substring` method is used the same way the Java one is.